# Crypto JS code output does not match C# code output

Tags: javascript, c#, cryptojs

I have some C# code that uses AES 256 to encrypt data, using a custom key and iv. I'm trying to recreate the code using CryptoJS library. They give different outputs, and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

The input for both is string '675675'.

C# code gives `yzFi7xGovxl0qcLsMoXZ9Q==` while JS code gives `zJtuaFJcJdeSfZxneb6bTYDPjoH3QAz87HTaaLyn5Zc=`

Here's the C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;




namespace Whatever.Class
{
    public class Program 
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        string moo = Encrypt_AES256.Encrypt256("675675", "5TGB&BJD!(JM(IK<5TGB&YHN7UJM(IK<", "!QAYDF7N#EDC4RFV");
        Console.WriteLine(moo+"\n");
    
       }
    }
    public class Encrypt_AES256
    {
        public static string Encrypt256(string text, string AesKey256, string AesIV256)
        {
            // AesCryptoServiceProvider
            AesCryptoServiceProvider aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();
            aes.BlockSize = 128;
            aes.KeySize = 256;
            aes.IV = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(AesIV256);
            aes.Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(AesKey256);
            aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

            byte[] src = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(text);

            using (ICryptoTransform encrypt = aes.CreateEncryptor())
            {
                byte[] dest = encrypt.TransformFinalBlock(src, 0, src.Length);

                // Convert byte array to Base64 strings
                return Convert.ToBase64String(dest);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the JS code I attempted to write, using CryptoJS lib:

```
const encryptWithAES = message => {
    const key = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create('5TGB&BJD!(JM(IK<5TGB&YHN7UJM(IK<');
    const iv = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create('!QAYDF7N#EDC4RFV');
    const wordArray = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create(message);

    const cipher = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(wordArray, key, {
      iv,
      padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7,
      mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
    });

    return  cipher.toString();
}

console.log(encryptWithAES('675675'));
```

What am I doing wrong in the JS code?

Assumptions:

1. I couldn't find any equivalent for mentioning BlockSize and KeySize like in C#. It looks like CryptoJS picks that up on its own when reading the key and iv input.
2. Using base64 still didn't give me the right answer, so I didn't add it in the code sample.

Comment: I had modified the keys before creating the question

Comment: I would check encoding type that is being used to encode text in bytes both in C# and in javascript.